# Dúvida sobre relações hierárquicas entre classes e slots

Tags: aplicação-web, semântica, owl, ontologia

Eu estou tentando fazer uma **ontologia** de um **hospital** e tenho as classes:

> Fisioterapeuta, Médico, Psicólogo e Nutricionista

Dentro da classe `Médico`, eu tenho algumas especialidades - dentre elas:

> Oncologia

**Como eu faço pra dizer que um paciente tem câncer quando for tratado por um médico da especialidade de `Oncologia`?**

*Pretendo generalizar a resposta para outras relações entre as especialidades.*

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Ícaro! Quando puder, faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber um pouco mais sobre como o site funciona (é bem rápido, e vale uma medalha!)

Answer (score 1):

Para inferir que

> "Todo paciente que é tratado por um médico oncologista tem câncer"

você pode criar, utilizando o Protégé, uma classe `Paciente_com_Cancer` e definí-la como sendo equivalente a (Equivalent To):

> Paciente and (eh_paciente_do_medico some Medico_Oncologista)

Assim, um indivíduo `p` da ontologia vai pertencer à classe `Paciente_com_Cancer` se:

- `p` pertencer à classe `Paciente`; e
- `p` tiver a propriedade `eh_paciente_do_medico` com um indivíduo `m`; e
- `m` pertencer à classe `Medico_Oncologista`

Para melhorar a ontologia, podemos fazer mais uma inferência associando o paciente `p` ao nome da doença `cancer`:

1. criar uma propriedade `tem_doenca`
2. criar a instância `cancer` pertencente à classe `Doença`
3. criar uma regra usando a Semantic Web Rule Language (SWRL):

   > Paciente_com_Cancer(?p) -> tem_doenca(?p, cancer)

   Traduzindo... se `p` pertencer à classe `Paciente_com_Cancer`, então `p` `tem_doenca` `cancer`.

No final da resposta está o código da ontologia OWL que eu fiz usando o Protégé. Coloquei a ontologia [aqui](http://webprotege.stanford.edu/#Edit:projectId=a3ec5b54-6558-4155-9f47-1a25eea04a5c) também, se quiser baixá-la. Rodei o reasoner (algoritmo que usa a lógica para buscar as inferências) Pellet e as inferências deram certo!

Para testar a ontologia, criei os seguintes fatos:

> andre é um Medico_Oncologista.
>
> cancer é uma Doenca.
>
> joao é um Paciente.
>
> joao é paciente do medico andre

A partir dessas informações e das classes e propriedades que modelamos anteriormente, o algoritmo reasoner inferiu corretamente o seguinte:

> joao é um Paciente_com_Cancer.
>
> joao tem_doenca cancer.

### Ontologia OWL

```
Prefix(:=<http://www.example.com/hospital#>)
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)


Ontology(<http://www.example.com/hospital>

### As Classes ###

Declaration(Class(:Doenca))
Declaration(Class(:Fisioterapeuta))
Declaration(Class(:Medico))
Declaration(Class(:Medico_Oncologista))
Declaration(Class(:Nutricionista))
Declaration(Class(:Paciente))
Declaration(Class(:Paciente_com_Cancer))
Declaration(Class(:Profissionais))
Declaration(Class(:Psicologo))

### As Propriedades ###

Declaration(ObjectProperty(:eh_paciente_do_medico))
Declaration(ObjectProperty(:tem_doenca))
Declaration(ObjectProperty(:tem_paciente))

### Alguns indivíduos (instâncias das Classes) ###

Declaration(NamedIndividual(:andre))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(:cancer))
Declaration(NamedIndividual(:joao))

### Relações entre as Classes ###

SubClassOf(:Fisioterapeuta :Profissionais)
SubClassOf(:Medico :Profissionais)      # Medico é uma subclasse de Profissionais
SubClassOf(:Medico_Oncologista :Medico)
SubClassOf(:Nutricionista :Profissionais)

# Paciente_com_Cancer = Paciente E eh_paciente_do_medico Medico_Oncologista 
EquivalentClasses(:Paciente_com_Cancer ObjectIntersectionOf(ObjectSomeValuesFrom(:eh_paciente_do_medico :Medico_Oncologista) :Paciente))

SubClassOf(:Paciente_com_Cancer :Paciente)
SubClassOf(:Psicologo :Profissionais)
InverseObjectProperties(:tem_paciente :eh_paciente_do_medico)
ClassAssertion(:Medico_Oncologista :andre)  # andre é um Medico_Oncologista
ClassAssertion(:Doenca :cancer)             # cancer é uma Doenca
ClassAssertion(:Paciente :joao)             # joao é um Paciente
ObjectPropertyAssertion(:eh_paciente_do_medico :joao :andre)    #joao é paciente do medico andre

### Regras ###

# Regra em SWRL: Paciente_com_Cancer(?x) -> tem_doenca(?x, cancer)
# Se fulano pertencer à classe Paciente_com_Cancer, então podemos inferir que: fulano tem_doenca cancer 
DLSafeRule(Body(ClassAtom(:Paciente_com_Cancer Variable(<urn:swrl#x>)))Head(    ObjectPropertyAtom(:tem_doenca Variable(<urn:swrl#x>) :cancer)))
```

)